# Excel: convert float number to time

Tags: excel, time, numbers

In Excel I need to convert float numbers to time.

For example: 
8,3 must become 08:30
10 must become 10:00
11,3 must become 11:30

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: How do you denote AM/PM or is it in military time?

Comment: @xQbert - It's not really military time. It's the ISO 8601 international standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
=(INT(A1)+(A1-INT(A1))/0.6)/24
```

```
Input | Output  
----- | --------
8.3   | 08:30:00
10    | 10:00:00
11.3  | 11:30:00
```